# como puedo enviar un archivo por ajax sin utilizar el submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, formdata

este es mi evento click de un botón cuando quiero editar la información

```
$("#editarvacaciones").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

   //obtenemos los datos del formulario
    var form = $('#formulariovacaciones')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    var id = $('#vacaciones_id').val(); 
    // imprimimos los valores del formData 
    for (var data of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(data[0]+ ', ' + data[1]); 
    }

    console.log(formData);

    var url = '/vacaciones/' + id;
    var type = "PUT";
    var res = post_form(formData, url, type);
});
```

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//en esta función hago mi petición ajax

```
/*Enviar sin submit*/

function post_form(formData, url, type) {
var response = null;
$.ajax({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    url: url,
    method: type,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    success: function (res) {
        $.notify(res.message, success_opt);
        response = res.data;
    },
    error: function (res) {
        if (res) {
            console.log(res);
            if(res.responseJSON.errors){
                $.each(res.responseJSON.errors, function(i, item) {                    
                    $.notify(item, error_opt);
                    response = res.data;
                });
            }else if(res.responseJSON.message){
                $.notify(res.responseJSON.message, error_opt);
                response = res.data;
            } 
        } else {
            $.notify('Error desconocido', error_opt);
        }
    },
});
return response;
}
```

cuando en mi controlador hago un dd($request->all()); me devuelve nulo como si no le enviara nada a controlador.

también probé enviar los datos de esta manera y no me funciono

```
    var formData = new FormData();    
    var id = $('#vacaciones_id').val(); 

    formData.append('id', id);
    formData.append('worker_id', $('#wiV').prop('value'));
    formData.append('start_date', $('#start_dateV').prop('value'));
    formData.append('end_date', $('#end_dateV').prop('value'));
    formData.append('reason', $('#reasonV').prop('value'));  

    var inputFileImage = document.getElementById("fileV");
    var file = inputFileImage.files[0]
    formData.append('file',file); 
    console.log(file);    


    // imprimimos los valores del formData 
    for (var data of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(data[0]+ ', ' + data[1]); 
    }
```

cuando imprimo los valores del `formData` este me devuelve lo que hay en los input todo bien pero cuando lo mande por ajax a mi controlador e igual hice un dd($request->all()); este me devuelve nulo []

Answer (score 0):

Creo que si vas a enviar un archivo usando AJAX necesitas incluir eso en los headers usando:

mimeType: "multipart/form-data"

```
        var file = this.files[0];
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append('file', file);
        form.append('text', $('#text').val());
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data"

            data : form,
            success: function(response){
                $('.result').html(response.html)
            }
        });
    });`
```